# What is the most suitable way to recreate/reassign a class from within a method?

Tags: python, class

Let's say that I have a class called School, which has a method called createSchool which will create a new instance of School and replace the existing instance (from which createSchool was called)...

The pseudo-code is below:

```
class School(object):
    def __init__(self,a=None,b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def createSchool(self,schoolFile):
        #...code to parse schoolFile and extract a,b and create a dict 
        # called schoolDict
        newClass = School(**schoolDict)
        #This step replaces the old dict with the new one, thereby reassigning all 
        # attributes.
        self.__dict__ = newClass.__dict__
```

My question is the thing that I did in the end with replacing the dictionary of the existing instance with that of the newly created one, the best way to go about it?

Thanks,
Sarith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A far better approach is to **not** obliterate the calling instance.  Instead, this should expressed as a classmethod

```
class School(object):
    def __init__(self,a=None,b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def createSchool(cls, schoolFile):
        # code to parse schoolFile and extract a,b and create a dict called schoolDict
        ... 
        return cls(**schoolDict)
```

Now we can use as:

```
school = School.createSchool(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. So you suggest not instantiating and creating an instance from scratch by parsing the file?

Comment: Absolutely ... think of your `createSchool` as another form of constructor for School

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use @classmethod decorator

```
class School(object):
    def __init__(self,a=None,b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @classmethod
    def createSchool(cls,schoolFile):
        schoolDict = parse(schoolFile)
        newClass = School(**schoolDict)
        return newClass
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could accept both your answers (as I got the same answer from two people!).

Comment: almost the same ... a `classmethod` will generally be wanting to use `cls` rather than an explicit class (`School`) to construct things ... this allows us to inherit nicely from `School`.

Comment: No problem, the other answer is more detailed.